# Spring Integration : TCP disable respnse read

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have the following requirement

> 1. Connect to socket (TCP)
> 2. Send initialization message [There will be no response from the server]
> 3. Check if the connection is live, if yes, send a polling message.
> 4. If there is a response process it.

I am trying to user Spring integration for the TCP connection, but when I try to perform the second step the framework waits for the response. Is there a way to configure it not to wait for the response in step 2?

Following is the Spring Configuration :

```
<int:gateway default-request-channel="msOutbound"
    service-interface="com.home.tcp.UserService" id="gw" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="tcpObGw"
    connection-factory="client" request-channel="msOutbound"
     />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" deserializer="serDeSer" serializer="serDeSer"
    host="remoteServer" port="valid port"  single-use="true" />

<bean id="serDeSer"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer" />
```

Java Code:

```
service.send("init msg"); // The program exits with no response exception.
service.send("polling message"); //Never executed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The gateway is a request/response mechanism (one request, one response). You have `single-use` set to `true` so even if the first one returned a response, the second one would go on another socket.

For your scenario, you need to set `single-use` to false and put a try/catch around the first `send` because you are expecting an exception there.

To improve timing, you should set the `remoteTimeout` on the gateway to a very small value (0) for just the first send, then increase it something reasonable.